# What is the best way and production-grade to deploy Airflow on GKE?

Tags: kubernetes, airflow, google-kubernetes-engine

I want to work with Airflow on Kubernetes (GKE).
What is the best way and production-grade to deploy it? (Kubernetes executor or Celery) We also want to work with the Kubernetes operators and run the tasks as pods.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Just the regular way (Celery), but we want to try the Kubernetes executor, and I don't know if it's stable or what is the best way to deploy it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE), use [Google Cloud Composer](https://cloud.google.com/composer/) which is a managed version of Apache Airflow on Google that is run on GKE.

Comment: I tried it, but we want more flexibility for provisioning and one more issue with that is the version, composer is beta (we don't like to deploy beta versions to production).

Comment: Check this out: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/airflow-operator to get some ideas on how they do it and you can build your own environment.